# "Socket.RemoteHost" in some networks returns IP instead of ComputerName - Delphi

Tags: sockets, delphi, serversocket

I'm using "OnClientConnect" of TServerSocket to identify when a client connects to chat, and save the ComputerName of the client in a listbox to manage sending messages between clients.

The code is like this:

```
    procedure TfrmAnaForm.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    var 
       ComputerName: string;
    begin    
        frmChatMain.lstChatUsers.Items.Add(Socket.RemoteHost);    
    end;
```

The problem is that Normally "Socket.RemoteHost" returns "ComputerName" of the client, but in some networks, the code "Socket.RemoteHost" returns IP of client instead of "ComputerName" of client.

Comment: How will the server know the computername ... the network level connection works with a network address (IP Address) so to get a computername it will need to look up the computername.  There are different ways that can be done including use of a hosts file and reverse DNS, but if the server can't resolve the comutername it can't give it to you.  In a messaging application its quite normal to exchange information between the client and server which is not part of the chat, this could include an identifier (computername or username) for the client.

Answer (score 0):

The `RemoteHost` property retrieves the client's IP address from the socket, and then performs a reverse DNS lookup of the client's hostname for that IP.  If that lookup fails, `RemoteHost` returns a blank string, not the IP address.  The only way `RemoteHost` can return an IP address is if that is what the DNS system actually reported.

You should not be using the `RemoteHost` to uniquely identify clients, because 1) it is not guaranteed to even give you a value, and 2) it is not guaranteed to be unique, such as if multiple remote clients are connecting from the same computer/network. At the very least, you must use `RemoteIP`+`RemotePort` instead of `RemoteHost` to identify individual connections.  Though, you really should be using the `TCustomWinSocket` object itself to identify unique connections.  Even better, require clients to login to your server with a unique ID, which you can then store inside the `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property so it follows the connection it belongs to.